# MySQLi Transaction Succeeds with bind_param Warning

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been playing with `mysqli` transactions and have come across an issue. When I intend for both of my queries to fail because I have messed with one of the `bind_param()`s, the `rollback()` will not be called because `bind_param` only throws a warning. I was under the impression that transactions only completed if all queries inside were successful. In this case only one was successful.

```
try{
    $mysqli->begin_transaction();

    $stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES (?)');    
    $stmt1->bind_param('s',$name);
    $stmt1->execute();

    $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO test2 (test) VALUES (?)');   
    $stmt2->bind_param('ss',$test);
    $stmt2->execute();

    $mysqli->commit();
}catch(Exception $e){
    $mysqli->rollback();
    error_log($e);
    exit('We have caught an exception!');
}
```

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type
>   definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in...

I understand that this is a warning I would just expect that if this query fails it would not allow the transaction to stay committed.

My connection is basic

```
$test = new mysqli('localhost:3306','root','','test');
```

Comment: Could you show the full warning/error message?  A warning isn't necessarily an error, nor is it necessarily a transaction-voiding exception.

Comment: @richyen see my edit please

Comment: Do you have the mysqli exception mode switched on properly? Your execute call should trigger exception, not bind_param.

Comment: @Dharman please see edit 2

Comment: Do you have `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` in your code?

Comment: @Dharman I have been in the practice of adding that to scripts for testing and then removing once I no longer need it. I this allowed in a production environment?

Comment: Yes! What exceptions do you expect to happen if you have them switched off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To catch an exception first you need a piece of code, which would throw it. By default MySQLi silently ignores all your problems. It might warn you, but it will not throw an exception. You need to enable MySQLi error reporting by switching the exception mode, if you want it to work.

The correct database connection using mysqli consists of 3 steps:

1. Enable mysqli error reporting.
2. Create an instance of mysqli class
3. Set the correct connection charset

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'somePassword', 'dbName');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```

It is perfectly safe to have error reporting in production environment as long as you never display them to the end-users. This means that you must set [`display_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) to `0` in your productive INI configuration.